# In Ignite Data Grid，how many Bytes should an object take in Memory

Tags: ignite

In Ignite Data Grid, how many Bytes should the object be in Memory？

I see: Total 77 Bytes, is this right?

```
Car{
id=26f32f831d724303a0de972174503e65,//32 bytes
plateNumber='京AAVO10',             //9  bytes
createAt=FriOct2811: 44: 04CST2016,  // 4 bytes
barrierId='00000000000000000000000000000354'  //32 bytes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object is 77 bytes but there will be additional overhead of around 200 bytes that has to be taken into account.

Please take a look here: http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/docs/capacity-planning

Regards,
Den

Comment: plateNumber could be 18 bytes, not 9 if your implementation is UTF-16

Comment: Capacity Memory:77 bytes + 77*0.3(indexs)  bytes + 200 bytes = 300bytes /entity   is it right?

Comment: but when 3,000,000 objects put into   memory,capacity of memory is about 3GB?why?

Comment: `public class Car implements Serializable {
    /** */
    private static final AtomicLong ID_GEN = new AtomicLong();

    @QuerySqlField(index = true)
    public String id;


    @QuerySqlField(index = true)
    public String plateNumber;


    @QuerySqlField(index = true,descending = true)
    public Date createAt;

 
    @QueryTextField
    public String barrierId;

}`

Comment: but when 3,000,000 objects put into   memory,capacity of memory is about 3GB?why?

Comment: `IgniteCache<String, Car> carCache = Ignition.ignite().cache(CAR_CACHE);
       
            Car car = new Car("中AAAAAA","000000000000000000000000000", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

            carCache.put(car.id, car); `